# processing error with civicrm 4.7.31 & stripe 4.7.3 on Wordpress 4.9.4

Tags: wordpress, civimember, stripe

I'm getting this error from members trying to sign up, but it's intermittent so I'm wondering if it's browser related:

"Processing Error
An error occurred while processing your transaction.

Please review the error message below and click here to modify your information and try again.

Error Message: The supplied unique organisation name was invalid.

Error Code:07"

The last change I made was an incremental upgrade from 4.7.2* to 4.7.31. It maybe have started then.

I can't even work out what's generating that error message.

We do not accept any other payment method, even offline.

Our membership pages do not ask for organisation name.

I do see this in the Javascript on the page when viewing the source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  CRM.$(function($) {

    var orgOption = $("input:radio[name=org_option]:checked").attr('id');
    var onBehalfRequired = '$onBehalfRequired';
    var onbehalfof_id = $('#onbehalfof_id');
    var is_for_organization = $('#is_for_organization');

    selectCreateOrg(orgOption, false);

    if (is_for_organization.length) {
      $('#on-behalf-block').toggle(is_for_organization.is(':checked'));
    }

    is_for_organization.on('change', function(){
      $('#on-behalf-block').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });

   $("input:radio[name='org_option']").click( function( ) {
     var orgOption = $(this).attr('id');
     selectCreateOrg(orgOption, true);
   });
```

Any ideas?

Dan

Comment: Hi, could you detail how you set up your member sign up page? presumably it's with a payment on stripe, but do you have other payment method? what data do you ask from your members? is there anything related to organisation name?

Comment: Hi Xavier.  I've edited the above to clarify.

Comment: Can anyone else help with this?